# Replace value in php not works as expected

Tags: php

I am having a file like this and I am trying to replace the file:

**abc.txt**

```
# Define the right-hand side of the equation:
#{xvalue1#}xval1= ;#xvalue1
#{xvalue2#}xval2= ;#xvalue2
```

What I did is as follows:

```
$myfile = fopen("abc.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data = fread($myfile,filesize($pgm_file));

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$parsed0 = get_string_between($data, "#{xvalue1#}xval1=", ";#xvalue1");
$parsed1 = get_string_between($data, "#{xvalue2#}xval2=",";#xvalue2");
```

I am trying to replace the values as follows:

```
$datanew0 = str_replace($parsed0,"5", $data);
$datanew1 = str_replace($parsed1,"10", $datanew0);
```

When I echoed `echo $datanew1;`
I am getting output as :

```
# Define the right-hand side of the equation:
    #{xvalue1#}xval1= 5;#xvalue1
    #{xvalue2#}xval2= 5;#xvalue2
```

My expected result is:

```
# Define the right-hand side of the equation:
    #{xvalue1#}xval1= 5;#xvalue1
    #{xvalue2#}xval2= 10;#xvalue2
```

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do? If *abc.txt* is as given above `$parsed0` and `$parsed1` will be `' '`.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 right buddy. In that place I need to ad my values as mentioned above!!

Comment: But why would you extract that whitespace? If you want to insert at that position just take the position within the string and put your stuff in there with `substr()` and concatenation.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 if you can put it as an answer it will be most helpful!!

Comment: I've posted an example below. Feel free to add a comment if it doesn't match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to rather work with the positions within the string than extracting and replacing stuff.

Take a look at this example

```
function injectBetween($what, $start, $end, $src){
    $lpos = strpos($src, $start);
    $rpos = strrpos($src, $end);
    return substr($src, 0, $lpos + strlen($start)) . $what . substr($src, $rpos);
}

var_dump(injectBetween('test', 'start', 'end', 'startend'));
```

Will give you `string 'starttestend' (length=12)`

Or to match your example:

```
var_dump(injectBetween('5', '#{xvalue1#}xval1= ', ';#xvalue1', '#{xvalue1#}xval1= ;#xvalue1'));
```

---

I don't know how your full input looks like. If you have multiple lines that have the same pattern this will most probably fail. Better use regular expressions in that case or parse your input line by line (using `explode()`).

Comment: It is replacing where ever space it is having with the value. I want to replace in between that particular strings only. So it not help at all!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using **RegEx** ? it is more appropriate, efficient and maintainable implementation :

```
<?php
    $subject = "#{xvalue1#}xval1= 19;#xvalue1";
    $pattern = "/#\{xvalue[0-9]+#\}xval[0-9]+= ([0-9]+);#xvalue[0-9]+/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matchs);
    var_dump($matchs);
```

**EDIT:**
I suggest you to change your pattern like this :

```
#{xvalue#}xval1= ;#xvalue
```

And the **RegEx** pattern will be :

```
$pattern = "/#\{xvalue#\}xval([0-9]+)= ([0-9]+);#xvalue/";
```

Note that i have also captured the key associated to your value

Comment: He's trying to inject stuff - not extract. Better use `preg_replace()`